# EF Core Adding two instances of the same object in a controller System.InvalidOperationException

Tags: mysql, asp.net-core, ef-database-first, ef-core-2.0

I am trying to add two instances of the same object in the same request and controller.  I feel like this is a fairly common operation, but EF Core seems to have an issue with this. I am working on an accounting system, where you always have 2 transactions recorded.

```
private void AddLedgersForTrade(Trade trade)
    {

        decimal TradeTranFee = 0;
        decimal ForTranFee = 0;

        if(trade.TradeCoinId == trade.FeeCoinId){
            TradeTranFee = trade.Fee;
        } else {
            ForTranFee = trade.Fee;
        }
        var ledger1 = new LedgerTransaction{
            TransactionId = trade.TransactionId,
            TransactionDate = trade.TradeDate,
            ExchangeId = trade.FromExchangeId,
            CoinId = trade.TradeCoinId,
            Amount = trade.TradeAmount * -1,
            ExchangeRate = 1,
            Fee = TradeTranFee,
            LastUpdate = trade.LastUpdate,
            TradeId = trade.Id,
            Owner = trade.Owner
        };
        var ledger2 = new LedgerTransaction{
            TransactionId = trade.TransactionId,
            TransactionDate = trade.TradeDate,
            ExchangeId = trade.ToExchangeId,
            CoinId = trade.ForCoinId,
            Amount = trade.ForAmount,
            ExchangeRate = trade.ExchangeRate,
            Fee = ForTranFee,
            LastUpdate = trade.LastUpdate,
            TradeId = trade.Id,
            Owner = trade.Owner
        };

        ledgerRepository.AddLedgerTransaction(ledger1);
        ledgerRepository.AddLedgerTransaction(ledger2);

    }
```

The first works fine, but once it tries to add the 2nd transaction, I get the error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: The instance of entity type 'LedgerTransaction' cannot be tracked because another instance with the key value 'Id:0' is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached.
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.IdentityMap`1.Add(TKey key, InternalEntityEntry entry) ....

My Context is setup for this entity as:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<LedgerTransaction>(entity =>
        {

            entity.HasIndex(e => e.CoinId);

            entity.HasIndex(e => e.ExchangeId);

            entity.HasIndex(e => e.IsManual);

            entity.HasIndex(e => e.Owner);

            entity.HasIndex(e => e.TradeId);

            entity.Property(e => e.Id).ValueGeneratedNever();

            entity.Property(e => e.ExchangeId).HasDefaultValueSql("'0'");

            entity.Property(e => e.IsManual).HasDefaultValueSql("'b\\'0\\''");

            entity.Property(e => e.LastUpdate).HasDefaultValueSql("'0001-01-01 00:00:00'");
        });
```

I read this may be a bug in EF Core 2.0.x, but I'm at a loss.  I tried adding AsNoTracking() to the query for my initial "Trade" entity, but still having the same issue.  What is funny, is I started as a code-first EF project, but then scaffolded the database and went database-first.  Everything worked fine with code-first approach.  I'm guessing this must be in the context somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you have set (missing from your snippet)

```
builder.Entity<Ledger>().HasKey(e => e.Id);
```

but have omitted

```
builder.Entity<Ledger>().Property(e => e.Id).ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
```

And also, to avoid headaches if a merge between two instances of the same db is required I'd make the `Id` a `Guid` not an `int`.

Comment: Looks like the scaffold set my ID to ValueGeneratedNever() by default.  Must be related to Mysql library.  Adding ValueGeneratedOnAdd did the trick!

Comment: Would also love to use Guid, but Mysql does not handle this well on larger data sets, so going to stick with int for now.